# Why time complexity of brute force algorithm is O(n*m)?

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching, time-complexity, brute-force, string-search

I am using the following brute force algorithm for searching a string inside another string.

As I know, the number of comparisons is `(n-m+1)*m` in the worst case, but the right answer for time complexity is supposed to be `O(n*m)`.

To get this answer, I do the following transformations:

```
(n-m+1)*m = (n+1) * m - m^2 = O(n*m) - m^2
```

How do you get `O(n*m)` from here?

Where did `-m^2` go?

Brute force algorithm:

```
NAIVE-STRING-MATCHER

n = T.length
m = P.length
for s = 0 to n - m
    if P[1...m] == T[s+1...s+m]
        print s
```

Comment: I am sorry for my pool English and I don't know how to express it. Then you just answer how I get the NAIVE-STRING-MATCHER algorithm's time complexity O(n*m) when I know comparisions times is (n-m+1)*m.

Comment: O-Notation describes the upper bound. Since O(n*m) > O(n*m)-m^2 the upper bound is also O(n*m). Some will also argue that m is very small compared to n so it could be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

The running time indeed belongs to `O(m(n-m))`. But as the Big-O notation is an upper bound, this is also `O(mn)`, as `mn ≥ m(n-m)`.

In practice, no harm is done by this simplification, as you usually expect the length of the search string to be proportional to that of the pattern. Then `m = αn` yields `m(n-m) = mn(1-α)`.

Comment: Does ' the Big-O notation is an upper bound' mean I can ignore any negative term(here is m^2 - m) ? And 'm = αn yields m(n-m) = mn(1-α)', why it is not  m(n-m) = αn*n(1-α):  O(n^2) ?

Comment: @Sword: you can write that as well.